# Как узнать длину и высоту глифа в True Type?

Tags: шрифты

У меня есть True Type шрифт заданого размера в пикселях, мне нужно узнать минимальную высоту для площади текста и длину конкретного глифа так как нужно каретку рисовать возле него. Как рассчитать ето? У меня получается текст после рендера в пикселях больше чем заданая высота шрифта.
С помощью FontForge посмотрел метрики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Determining exact glyph height in specified font](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9924066/5045688) - оно?

Comment: Кстати, добавляйте больше меток к вопросу, чтобы его заметили. Конечно, лишние лепить не надо, но метка языка программирования, на котором желательно решение, не помешает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не совсем, мне бы программу а не код, или мат-часть

Comment: Ну, человече... Этот сайт про код, а не про поиск программ. И вообще, это сразу стоило написать в вопросе. / Думаю, стоит отредактировать пост, тогда он снова окажется на главной странице сайта - его увидят. Могут помочь, а могут и заминусовать (ибо не по теме)